# Динамически расположить элементы по кругу

Tags: html, css, frontend, scss

Добрый день. Есть задача - сверстать блок на фоне градиента (смотри скриншот, слева). 
Динамическое количество элементов располагаются радиально по границе круга. При наведении на элемент - ховер эффект. С чем я справился (смотри скриншот, справа).

Проблема в следующем: граница круга должна "прерываться" около иконки, иконка должна перекрывать целиком эту границу. Как это сделать?

Пытался шаманить с прозрачными границами и фоном у иконок - не вышло.

[ДЕМО](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apOgzX)

```
<ul class='advantages-circle'>

  <li class="advantages-circle__element">
    <img src='//i.imgur.com/y6KYdvS.png' alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="advantages-circle__element">
    <img src='//i.imgur.com/y6KYdvS.png' alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="advantages-circle__element">
    <img src='//i.imgur.com/y6KYdvS.png' alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="advantages-circle__element">
    <img src='//i.imgur.com/y6KYdvS.png' alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="advantages-circle__element">
    <img src='//i.imgur.com/y6KYdvS.png' alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="advantages-circle__element">
    <img src='//i.imgur.com/y6KYdvS.png' alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="advantages-circle__element">
    <img src='//i.imgur.com/y6KYdvS.png' alt="">
  </li>

</ul>
```

---

```
body {
  background: rgb(59, 67, 113);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(59, 67, 113, 0.9) 0%, rgba(243, 144, 79, 0.9) 99%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(59, 67, 113, 0.9) 0%, rgba(243, 144, 79, 0.9) 99%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(59, 67, 113, 1) 0%, rgba(243, 144, 79, 1) 99%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3b4371', endColorstr='#f3904f', GradientType=0);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

@mixin distribute-on-circle( $nb-items, $circle-size, $item-size) {
  $half-item: ($item-size / 2);
  $half-parent: ($circle-size / 2);
  position: relative;
  width: $circle-size;
  height: $circle-size;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  > * {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: $item-size;
    height: $item-size;
    margin: -$half-item;
  }
  $angle: (360 / $nb-items);
  $rot: 0;
  @for $i from 1 through $nb-items {
    >:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      transform: rotate($rot * 1deg) translate($half-parent) rotate($rot * -1deg);
    }
    $rot: ($rot + $angle);
  }
}

.advantages {
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  &-circle {
    @include distribute-on-circle(8, 30em, 6em);
    margin: 5em auto 0;
    border: 2px solid white;
    &__element {
      img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в демо картинки не открываются

Comment: Вариант послать в одно место дизайнера не рассматривается?

Comment: @L.Vadim странно, у меня открывается

Comment: @mJeevas Поздно, все уже согласовано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вроде того. Но математика для меня непосильная, поэтому я просто подогнал дуги как получилось. Если есть желание заморочится с точными расчетами, то посмотреть как считаются координаты дуг в svg можно тут - `http://shpargalkablog.ru/2015/11/svg.html`

Если кратко. Чтобы посчитать параметры одной други, нужно из центра окружности провести 2 луча проходящих через точки на окружности, которые ограничивают дугу (т.е. выделить сектор) и найти координаты этих точек (кажется r sin A и r cos А). В этих точках нужно построить касательные к окружности (т.е. взять производную, чтобы получить уравнения прямых). В svg нужно прописать координаты трех точек - точка начала дуги, точка окончания дуги и точка пересечения касательных. Тогда получится правильная дуга.

```css
.arc {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
.crc {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 500px;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}
div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(-150deg);
}
div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
div:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(-210deg);
}
div:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
}
div:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
}
div:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotate(-300deg);
}
div:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotate(-330deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="crc"></div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="arc">
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewbox="-5 -5 505 505">
    <path d="M200 0 Q160 10 140 20" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" style="fill: transparent;" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Я в скором времени обязательно приведу результат, получилось очень даже неплохо, спасибо!